# OTA mDNS issues with ESP8266 and PlatformIO?

Tags: esp8266, ide, softap

The common useage of the OTA library for this MCU is to have it connect to a network, and to then use a computer on that network to upload firmware across that network. Due to <strike>either issues with PlatformIO (my IDE of choice right now) or</strike> my router (administrated by my ISP) blocking discovery (mDNS does NOT work here either way, and getting the IP is very hard as a result*), I would like to use the SoftAP class to make an access point that I can connect to directly when uploading firmware.

However, I have attempted this, and it *does* work IF I specify an IP address. This is a bit more convenient, but it *fails* if I try using mDNS again (via upload_port = myesp8266.local). (As an aside, this means that OTA over SoftAP does work, at least to this degree. I'm sure some will find this useful.)

Has anyone else confirmed either of these issues? I understand that they may be unrelated (since problem one is (Network || PIO) and the second is (PIO || SoftAP) as the cause), but any information as to why this might fail in both cases would be useful.

**So, for the first case, can someone who uses that IDE and has an ESP8266 board test if mDNS works with the IDE?
For the second, assuming that mDNS *does* work with the IDE in the first case (and it's thus the MCU's fault), can anyone determine why the SoftAP class either halts or fails to work with mDNS?**

This will really help my abilities to easily get firmware onto the board, and also tell me if I need to get a new router that allows mDNS (if it's not PlatformIO in the first case).

*Since the ISP administrates the router, I am unable to log in and view the IP addresses currently connected. My only option is printing it via UART, which renders this pointless, or attaching a OLED or LCD screen to every single device I build, or get a new router, which is its own issue right now. I've now run the web server test again, and not only does OTA not work with mDNS, but apparently I can't access it at all unless I know its actual IP address.

Comment: 1: I'm surprised the router can block mDNS, that's not how mDNS works - 2. PlatformIO works with mDNS 100% in my (Windows 10) experience ... what operating system are you using? Can you `ping myesp8266.local` - are you sure you have the correct host name for your ESP? 3. I've never attempted OTA using SoftAP

Comment: `can anyone determine why the SoftAP class either halts or fails to work with mDNS` - would've thought mDNS is redundant with SoftAP - since SoftAP means the ESP has a known fixed address, 192.168.4.1 (by default)

Comment: `that's not how mDNS works` - I guess a router could block mDNS if it wanted to, seems like an unlikley scenario though

Comment: I had to perform that experiment again, and apparently I remembered wrong -- the web server is also not accessible. I can't even access the esp8266.local address even if I *can* access its IP directly. That's apparently for *any* networking feature if it's attached to my home network.

Comment: So you can't access the esp by ip address either?

Comment: No, I cannot. Chromium simply says that it can't find the address. PlatformIO complains of the same issue, saying that esp8266.local cannot be found.